# Sitecore : Method not found: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

Version: Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140526.exe, MVC 5

I am trying to do a small poc with Sitecore MVC. Where I have defined some placeholder in the layout and I have added some components.Now if I am trying to view the page I get below issue.

Any Idea??

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that the `Sitecore.Mvc.dll` is available in the bin-folder of your website?

Comment: Yes Kevin..I have that dll in the bin folder.

Comment: Are you sure you have the .mvc config files in place ? What guide have you followed to set up the sitecore mvc app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue some time ago after upgrading from Sitecore 7 (MVC3) to Sitecore 7.2 (MVC5). The cause was an old version of the `Sitecore.Mvc.dll` that was being copied into my website's bin folder on compile.

The (file) version you need of the file is `1.0.0.4757`. Mine was still 1.0.0.3xx-something. Don't mix this up with the version that's displayed in Visual Studio, as both files show up identically as being `1.0.0`.